# Malformed \N character escape

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
File "<ipython-input-15-155e515d797c>", line 3
    DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'file:H:\New_folder\models\research\object_detection'
                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 7-8: malformed \N character escape
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) especially #1 and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to escape the backslashes in your file path.

So the line should be:

```
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'file:H:\\New_folder\\models\\research\\object_detection'
```

Comment: Or use a raw string: `r'file:H:\New_folder\models\research\object_detection'`